# Having issue's with a confusing access violation? - C , OpenGL 3.3+ , SDL 2.0+

Tags: opengl, sdl, c

Hello this code seems so well done and yet I'm getting this weird access violation error when I use anything but 0 in glShaderSources 2nd argument :

```
glShaderSource( fragshader, 0, fragfilebuff, NULL );
```

If I use lenofstr or any other number then 0 it calls up an error like this :

[image: error]

I have no idea for the life of me why this is happpening
I've updated my drivers , I've even tried messing around with glewInit();
too see if it's something to do with that but no luck what so ever.

This nvidia dll has some problem with my code and I don't know why?...

```
void LoadShaders(const char *fragshaderfn, const char *vertshaderfn)
{
    FILE *fragfile;
    const GLchar *fragfilebuff[256] = { 0 };
    fopen_s(&fragfile, fragshaderfn, "r");

    fread(fragfilebuff, sizeof(char), sizeof(char) * 256, fragfile);
    printf(fragfilebuff);

    GLsizei lenofstr = strlen(fragfilebuff);
    printf("this is the length -> %d", lenofstr);

    GLuint fragshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(fragshader, 0,
        fragfilebuff, NULL);

    glCompileShader(fragshader);

};
```

Here's the complete source :

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640


SDL_Renderer *mainrenderer;
SDL_Window *mainwindow;
SDL_Event event;
bool running = true;


void LoadShaders(const char *fragshaderfn, const char *vertshaderfn)
{
    FILE *fragfile;
    const GLchar *fragfilebuff[256] = { 0 };
    fopen_s(&fragfile, fragshaderfn, "r");

    fread(fragfilebuff, sizeof(char), sizeof(char) * 256, fragfile);
    printf(fragfilebuff);

    GLsizei lenofstr = strlen(fragfilebuff);
    printf("this is the length -> %d", lenofstr);

    GLuint fragshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(fragshader, lenofstr,
        fragfilebuff, NULL);

    glCompileShader(fragshader);

};


int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    mainwindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "C OpenGL Engine",
        300, 300, 640, 480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL );

    SDL_GLContext maincontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainwindow);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(mainwindow, maincontext);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();

    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));

    if (SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1) < 0)
    {
        printf("Warning: Unable to set VSync! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    LoadShaders("ffile.frag", "");

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    while (running == true)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(maincontext);
                    SDL_Quit();

                    return 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(maincontext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mainwindow);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

All help would be appreciated I am using C , SDL 2.0 and OpenGL 3.3+ , 
MSVC 2015 , Win10 64bit

Comment: Easy: `glShaderSource( fragshader, 1, &fragfilebuff, NULL );` if your string has a `0x00` at the end. Replace `NULL` with `&fragfilelen` if not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void glShaderSource(GLuint shader,
    GLsizei count,
    const GLchar **string,
    const GLint *length);
```

Okay, I guess you didn't understand what these values mean.
string is an "array"(pointer is more correct since a pointer is not an array) of "char const*" (I advice you to put all your code in one and only one char const *.

length is an "array" of int. Each values inside this "array" should be set  at the length of the respective "char const*" in "string".

Count is just the number of char const* and int you have in both array above.

So, I'd go for that :

```
char const *code = getStringFromFile(path);
int length = strlen(code);
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &code, &length);
```

That should work :)

the getStringFromFile(path) could be done like this:

```
const char *getStringFromFile(char const *path) {
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "ab"); // open the file at the end and binary
    int length = ftell(file); // Ask the size of the file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // return to the beginning of the file
    char *buffer = calloc(length + 1, sizeof(char)); // alloc the buffer with the end 0
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), length, file); // read the file
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}
```

This code may countain error, I didn't test it, but the idea is here

Comment: omg someone answered : D , I'll study this so much
and see if I can make it work.

I should say that I did know an array might be needed however
wasn't entirely shore how strict it was about that so good for clarifying.

Comment: Good luck, if you did not understand something, please, let me know.

Btw, by getStringFromFile, I mean a function which put all the file into one buffer and return it. (Don't forget to free it)

Comment: It is a c++ code I made, but maybe it could help you
https://github.com/qnope/GLTools/blob/master/System/GL/Pipeline/shader.cpp

Comment: I'll check it and yes if i do not understand something I'll defiantly without a shadow of a doubt be right here again : ).

Comment: Antonie Morrier  I must say I'm confused as why this code works ,
 I'm glad that it is by the way just wanted too know why exactly I needed too make a const char *getstringfromfile function and use that in glshadersource instead of just giving it the buffer, is this because OpenGL can't read the buffer and needs you to do it for it?

Comment: OpenGL does not have any function to read inside a file. The function getStringFromFile is for you to get the data from a file and put it inside one char const*.

I wrote a function in my answer that could help yo

Comment: Oh I see so OpenGL is even more stupider then I thought : D 
that will be logged for enternity lol.

I'll look at your function some more defiantly if I get in trouble 
again I've actually looked at it very well written for c++ .

Comment: Be careful if you use OpenGL and C++ together ^^.
But OpenGL is not stupid, its role is just to "use" the video card and draw triangles to screen using it. It is even not his role to create the window, or the context ^^.
Your choices to use SDL2 is really good. If you want to "steal" the code I sent before, or other code in the same repository, feel free for it ;)

Comment: I'm sticking to c as it is more compatible with opengl and clarifications galore yum .

I've got your code in a comment on my c file 
so if I need it boom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38393/discussion-between-dominic-hughes-and-antoine-morrier).